# Async controller method not returning

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, async-await

This code hangs (does not return a response) when I make a request to it:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<IQueryable<int>> Get()
    {
        return await new Task<IQueryable<int>>(() => new List<int>().AsQueryable());
    }
}
```

But this method works fine:

```
public IQueryable<int> Get()
{
    return new List<int>().AsQueryable();
}
```

What fundamental knowledge am I missing??!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the other answer noted, the reason your controller is not finishing is because the task is not started. However, using `Task.Start`, `Task.Factory.StartNew`, or `Task.Run` is not a good solution on ASP.NET.

The entire point of using `async`/`await` on ASP.NET is to *free up a thread*. However, if you `await` a task that is started via `Start`/`StartNew`/`Run`, then you're freeing up one thread by taking up *another* thread from the same thread pool. In this case, you not only lose all the benefits of `async`/`await`, but you actually *decrease* your scalability by regularly throwing off the ASP.NET thread pool heuristics.

There are [two types of tasks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html), as I describe on my blog: Delegate Tasks (which represent some work executed on a thread) and Promise Tasks (which represent an event). You should avoid Delegate Tasks on ASP.NET, including any tasks that are "started" (`Start`/`StartNew`/`Run`).

Since you're returning an `IQueryable<T>`, I'm assuming that your actual underlying operation is a database query. If you're using EF6, then you have full support for [asynchronous queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819165.aspx), which are properly implemented with Promise Tasks.

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually starting your `Task` so it will wait for something that will never begin.

Instead use `Task.Factory.StartNew` which will create and start at the same time, or call `Task#Start` and await that call.

An overview of ways to start a task: http://dotnetcodr.com/2014/01/01/5-ways-to-start-a-task-in-net-c/

Comment: Sure, there are plenty of different ways to start the Task. They might have a slightly different effect depending on what you do exactly but in such a trivial example as here it should be fine either way. Most important aspect is actually starting the task.

Comment: Doh! Thanks. I've misunderstood await, I thought it also ensured the task ran.

Comment: @Chris: you should accept Stephen's answer instead of mine, it's way better.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel duly done, I agree it's a better answer but you solved my initial dumb question, so thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need in `async`/`await` there, the method can look like:

```
public Task<IQueryable<int>> Get()
{
    return Task.FromResult(new List<int>().AsQueryable());
}
```

If you really need it to be `async`, ok, you can always write something like:

```
public async Task<IQueryable<int>> Get()
{
    return await Task.FromResult(new List<int>().AsQueryable());
}
```

which will introduce little overhead (a whole state machine will be generated by compiler).

Also, as others already stated, tasks returned from `async` methods should be **hot** (started)

Keep in mind, that `Task.FromResult` will return completed task and this case can be optimized by `async/await` generated code, writing `Task.Run` in this case is at least wierd

Read [*Task-based Asynchronous Pattern*](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957) for more details